# Trying to understand .bst syntax

Tags: bibtex, stack

I am trying to understand the syntax of .bst-files using the Guide [Tame the Beast](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf). For starters, I want to understand the example of the multiplication function on page 39 (The functions skip$ and if$ are explained on pages 33 to 35):

The first assignment in the function looks like this:

```
'a :=
```

Which is described as "We store the first value".

I know about stack-oriented programming and reverse polish notation, but I never actually coded it myself. What does the apostrophe do here? Is it related to "storing"? Sometomes I also see functions (such as skip$) with a preceding apostrophe. What is the meaning of this?

Comment: `'skip$` means “put `skip$` on the stack”, rather than making it act.

Comment: skip$ is a function, how do I put a function on the stack?

Comment: *Everything* is put on the stack, but this way, `skip$` will do its work later on, when it happens to be at the top of the stack.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `'` here means that rather than trying to evaluate `a` here, BibTeX will use the name itself. It the construct

```
'a :=
```

there will be some integer on the stack (let's call it `1`), so we actually have

```
#1 'a :=
```

This will assign variable `a` as `1`. If we didn't have the `'`, BibTeX would try to evaluate `a` here. As `a` will have been declared as an integer, that would mean that the value would be placed into the stack here. So something like

```
#1 'a :=
#2 a =
   { } % True code
   { } % False code
 if$
```

works (and here is false): the second use of `a` inserts the value into the sack so we can do the comparison.

---

The `'` syntax is also used to avoid needing to have brace groups around a one step branch in a conditional. It's used in constructs such as

```
[test]
  'skip$ % True branch
  { }    % False branch
if$
```

most commonly with `skip$` (do nothing) or `pop$` (pop the top item from the stack). Without the `'` and the `{ }` group, BibTeX would try to execute the function at the wrong time, and odd errors would result. (Here of course one could just use a brace group for the desired outcome.) The underlying concept is the same as the first case: put the quoted thing on the stack.

Comment: Well, in the example `a` and `b` are declared to be integer variables, but this doesn't really change the description.

Comment: Ok so if I understood correctly, it's equivalent to the single equal sign "=" for an assqignment vs double equals "==" for an evaluation?

Comment: @egreg I'd missed that this came from a set up where `a` is an integer: I've adjusted

Comment: @AlphaOmega Well not really as BibTeX uses `=` for the test and `:=` for the assignment, so those distinctions also apply

Comment: I see, and what exactly does the hashtag do? Does #1 simply mean to put 1 on top of the stack?

Comment: @AlphaOmega At the risk of explaining all of BibTeX in one answer + comments: strings are added to the stack by quoting in the form `"..."`, integers are added to the stack in the form `#...`.