# Natbib agsm - Remove comma between last name and first name & swap last and first name

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, overleaf, harvard-style

I'm using `natbib` for my bilbiography (and I'm working on Overleaf), and I want to have the same format as Harvard style for this, so I use the style `agsm`, but I want to have the first name then the last name and I want to remove comma between this. So for example:
I have this in my `.bib` file

```
@article{label1,
    author  = {Daniel Aubier and Nicole Silvie and Jean Tetrae}
    % ....}
```

And I have this kind of result actually:

> Aubier, D., Silvie, N. and Tetrae, J.

But I want this:

> D. Aubier, N. Silvie and J. Tetrae

I know this isn't the real Harvard style, but I want to keep the essential of Harvard style, with this particularity.

Thank for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you proceed as follows:

- Find the file `agsm.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file and call the copy, say, `myagsm.bst`. (Don't edit an original, unrenamed file from the the TeX distribution directly.) If you can't find the file inside Overleaf, you may try downloading it from

  ```
  https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/harvard/agsm.bst
  ```
- Open the file `myagsm.bst` in a text editor. The editor you use for your .tex files will do fine.
- In `myagsm.bst`, replace both instances of the string

  ```
  "{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, f.}"
  ```

  with the string

  ```
  "{f. }{vv }{ll}{, jj}"
  ```

  There are two instances of this string: one each in the functions `format.authors` and `format.editors`.
- Save the file `myagsm.bst` either in the directory where your main tex file is located or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter option, be sure to also update the filename database of your TeX distribution suitably.
- In your main tex file, change the instruction `\bibliographystyle{agsm}` to `\bibliographystyle{myagsm}` and perform a full recompile cycle -- LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more -- to fully propagate all changes.

Happy BibTeXing!

Two final comments/notes: (a) There is no unique harvard style, and it's not clear what a "real" harvard style might be. (b) Harvard style, also known as author-year style, is generally considered to be about the formatting of the *citation call-outs* rather than about the formatting of the bibliographic entries.

---

A full MWE (minimum working example):

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{label1,
  author = {Daniel Aubier and Nicole Silvie and Jean Tetrae},
  title  = {Thoughts},
  year   = 3001,
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[comma]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{myagsm}

\begin{document}
\citet{label1}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works :D
If I can take a little bit of your time, I would like to sort my bibliography by alphabetical order with the last name, is that possible ?

Comment: @Apodeus - `agsm` and `myagsm` automatically perform sorting of the entries, by alphabetical order of the surnames of the authors and editors.

Comment: Yes, but actualy it sorts with the initial of the First name, and I want it with last Name, with keeping the same format. Maybe in my `.bib` I'm wrong when I put author's names. I do it like this actually : `author  = {Aubier, D. and Blengino, J. M. and Brandt, A. C. and Silvie, N.}`

Comment: @Apodeus - It definitely sounds like there could be some input errors in your bib file. Please post a *new query* to (a) post a couple of bib entries that aren't being sorted and (b) mention that you use the `agsm` bibliography style along with the `natbib` citation management package.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for the tip. Can you point me to the documentation to know how are the bst files exactly coded? I guess that `ff` (resp `ll`) stands for first (resp last) name and I guess `vv` and `jj` work in case the author's last name is "van Beethoven Jr."

Comment: I believe the standard reference is [Tame the Bst](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/) by Nicolas Markey. Do also check out [Trying to understand .bst syntax](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/384472/5001) and [BibTeX is not parsing my entries correctly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48326/5001) [shameless self-citation alert!].